# Mod Pagespeed is applied partially. Combining only few JS files and rest are not combined

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-pagespeed

I have **mod_pagespeed** installed for **apache** and for 1 website I have enabled it using **.htaccess**. Below is the .htaccess code :

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
ModPagespeed on
ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_javascript
ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace,elide_attributes
</IfModule>
```

Though combine JS is written. It doesn't combine all JS into 1 file and show it in 1 single script tag. Below is the script loaded after pagespeed is applied:

```
<script src="https://abcd.com/assets/js/jquery.min.js,qv=45.3.68.pagespeed.jm.g-Rqg9FLCg.js" type="application/javascript"></script>    <!-- jQuery library -->
<script type='application/javascript' src="https://abcd.com/assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js,qv=45.3.68.pagespeed.jm.2Zsi-Z0kKK.js"></script>
<!--<script type='application/javascript' src='//apis.google.com/js/client.js'></script>-->
<script src="https://abcd.com/assets/js/vvv.min.js,qv=45.3.68.pagespeed.jm.OArlW9Bphb.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://abcd.com/assets/allcityname.js,qv=45.3.68.pagespeed.jm.JXiJKJxgSu.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://abcd.com/assets/js/main.min.js?v=45.3.68" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://abcd.com/assets/js,_resize.min.js,qv==45.3.68+slick,_slick.min.js,qv==45.3.68+js,_bootstrap.min.js,qv==45.3.68+js,_jquery.lazyload.min.js,qv==45.3.68.pagespeed.jc.pvjzSa2SoT.js"></script><script>eval(mod_pagespeed_Qji7kQ8WQd);</script>
<script>eval(mod_pagespeed_8xEMAs4Z6t);</script>
<script>eval(mod_pagespeed_Xkz2mXB8$v);</script>
<script>eval(mod_pagespeed_dGnDIMpPX7);</script>
<script src="https://abcd.com/assets/js/jquery.history.min.js+jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js.pagespeed.jc.kZ5nzlQvQy.js"></script><script>eval(mod_pagespeed_RoTwDjZDVk);</script>
<script>eval(mod_pagespeed_V826YrUaHB);</script>
<!--    Jplayer   -->
<script src="https://abcd.com/assets/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js+jplayer.playlist.min.js.pagespeed.jc.7pI28NzBCM.js"></script><script>eval(mod_pagespeed_XRZZeeTqUR);</script>
```

Here is the script without pagespeed implementation.

```
<script src="https://abcd.com/assets/js/jquery.min.js?v=45.3.68" type="application/javascript"></script>    <!-- jQuery library -->
<script type='application/javascript' src="https://abcd.com/assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js?v=45.3.68"></script>
<!--<script type='application/javascript' src='//apis.google.com/js/client.js'></script>-->
<script src="https://abcd.com/assets/js/vvv.min.js?v=45.3.68" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://abcd.com/assets/allcityname.js?v=45.3.68" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://abcd.com/assets/js/main.min.js?v=45.3.68" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://abcd.com/assets/js/resize.min.js?v=45.3.68" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script type="application/javascript"  src="https://abcd.com/assets/slick/slick.min.js?v=45.3.68"></script>
<script type="application/javascript"  src="https://abcd.com/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js?v=45.3.68"></script>
<script type="application/javascript"  src="https://abcd.com/assets/js/jquery.lazyload.min.js?v=45.3.68"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://abcd.com/assets/js/jquery.history.min.js"></script>
<script type='application/javascript' src="https://abcd.com/assets/js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<!--    Jplayer   -->
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://abcd.com/assets/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://abcd.com/assets/js/jplayer.playlist.min.js"></script>
```

What is going wrong ?